# Visual Studio 2008 code snippet doesn't add Reference Assembly and/or Import Namespace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets, guidance-automation-tool

I'm developing some code snippet, and I experienced that Visual Studio doesn't automatically add Reference to specified assembly and doesn't import the specified namespace.

My snippet definition is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
        <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
            <Header>
                <Title>MyTryCatch</Title>
                <Shortcut>myTryCatch</Shortcut>
            </Header>
            <Snippet>
                <References>
                    <Reference>
                    <Assembly>MyAssembly.dll</Assembly>
                </Reference>
                </References>
                <Imports>
                    <Import>
                        <Namespace>MyNamespace</Namespace>
                    </Import>
                </Imports>
                <Declarations>
                    <Object Editable="true">
                        <ID>Message</ID>
                        <Type>String</Type>
                        <ToolTip>Error message</ToolTip>
                        <Default>message</Default>
                        <Function></Function>
                    </Object>
                </Declarations>
                <Code Language="csharp" Kind="" Delimiter="$">
    <![CDATA[try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new MyNamespace.MyException("$Message$", exception);
    }]]>
                </Code>
            </Snippet>
   </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Note that I'm referencing a custom MyAssembly.dll that is visible from "Add Reference" popup (.NET Tab).

When I use the above snippet by *myTryCatch* shortcut, I'm able to see the snippet code but no Reference added and no Import made.

How I can fix or debug this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is your choice of language.  Only VB.Net supports reference assemblies and importing of namespaces from a code snippet.  The C# engine will ignore these elements.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171438.aspx

Comment: Ah, that would explain why they chose the word Import instead of Using. When I tested the snippet on the MS site, I did change the language to C# w/o mentioning that part not even thinking that that could be the issue. The Snippet Editor didn't disable the field when I selected C# as I think it probably should have if it weren't supported. I'm amazed that C# developers haven't demanded this feature. On a side note. How did your answer get selected as *the* selected answer without me doing so. Does your 294K rep give you that ability?

Comment: @ChadD my rep doesn't give me any abilities like that :).  Not sure how it got selected as the answer without you doing it.

Comment: usually when I mark an answer as the answer, I can toggle it again. Yours is locked in (not that it doesn't desever to be marked as teh answer). Thanks.

Comment: Now I see. Somehow I thought your answer was a reply to my post, which asked the same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640850/creating-my-first-snippet-trying-to-auto-add-a-reference. It looks liek I added a dup.